# Address boundary error when invoke swapcontext()

Tags: c, coroutine, ucontext

I've written a simple program, use `ucontext` library. However, a **signal SIGSEGV (address boundary error)** occurred. The running env is MacOS. I do not know what's wrong I made?

#### Updated Here: Version 2

As @Jeremy suggest, we could use **static** on `main_context` and `work_context`. However, if we change `work_context` to an array, it still failed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include "ucontext.h"


static ucontext_t main_context;
static ucontext_t work_context[3];  // version 2: from ucontext_t to an array

static void counter()
{
    for (int c = 0; ; c++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "c = %d\n", c);
        sleep(5);  // avoid busy loop
    }
}

static ucontext_t* make_context1(ucontext_t *ucp,  void (*func)())
{
    getcontext(ucp);
    sigemptyset(&ucp->uc_sigmask);

    void *sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
    if (sp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    ucp->uc_stack = (stack_t) { .ss_sp = sp, .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ, .ss_flags = 0 };
    ucp->uc_link = &main_context;
    
    makecontext(ucp, func, 0);
    return ucp;
}

int main() {
    printf("start\n");
    make_context1(work_context, counter);
    make_context1(work_context+1, counter);  // added in version 2
    make_context1(work_context+2, counter);  // added in version 2

    swapcontext(&main_context, work_context);
    printf("main exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line does the SIGSEGV occur on?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the code runs without crashing if I change these two lines:

```
ucontext_t main_context;
ucontext_t work_context;
```

to this:

```
static ucontext_t main_context;
static ucontext_t work_context;
```

I'm sure there is a good explanation for this, but I don't know what it is :(

Comment: Hi, I changed the type of `work_context` to an array, and it failed again even if **static** is used.

Comment: I did get a bunch of `warning: 'swapcontext' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6` type of warnings when I compiled the code; it might be that MacOS's support for this API isn't quite up to snuff in current MacOS/X versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simple - `SIGSTKSZ` is too small of a stack for `printf`. Increase it. Quadruple it.

Move `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600` on top of the file. See `man feature_test_macros`.

Add `#include <signal.h>` for `sigemptyset`. Change `"ucontext.h"` into `<ucontext.h>`- it's a standard header.

Comment: `SIGSTKSZ` is 131072, 128K, still so small?  `#define SIGSTKSZ        131072  /* (128K)recommended stack size */`